Synchronization between workflows - deploy multiple services at same time
I have multiple services (like frontend, api etc) as docker containers on server. For CI/CD I'm using Github Actions where every service is separate workflow.
name: Frontend
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
    paths:
      - 'frontend/**'

So when I make some change on frontend code, it is building, testing and deployed.
Problem is - many commits are for multiple services at once, for example some feature required change on frontend and backend. This will lead to two workflows runs, but one will deploy sooner which leads to bugs on site.
I cannot find a solution (maybe some action in marketplace?) to fix that. I want all workflows executed by some commit to wait "before finish line" and execute last job (deploy) at same time.

You can chain your CI workflows to be dependent on each other and execute sequentially. Docs

I think the problem is less in the workflows than in the fact you have separate deployments you can't deploy separately. Use patterns like parallel changes to ship backwards-compatible updates where the specific order of deployment is not critical.

We solve this via bundling in Reliza Hub - product that we're building. All your components will make up a bundle and then you can choose to promote a single bundle to higher level environments rather than do it per component - see a sample tutorial here - https://worklifenotes.com/2024/05/27/kustomize-deployments-with-reliza-hub/
